# Dockerfile: Copy dependencies builded in slim base image to alpine

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim AS builder

ENV POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false

WORKDIR /code

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends graphviz-dev
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir poetry
RUN poetry install


FROM python:3.8.7-alpine3.13

# to make pytest (celery etc) be available and executable one must copy their executables directly
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/celery /usr/local/bin/pytest /usr/local/bin/

# IF OVERWRITE python IN /usr/local/bin ANYTHING DOES NOT WORK
#COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

WORKDIR /code
COPY pythonapline .

CMD ["pytest"]
```

Repo: https://github.com/albertalexandrov/slim-to-alpine/

As you can see there I am trying to build dependencies in python:3.8.7-slim base image and then copy all builded dependencies to python:3.8.7-alpine3.13.

Build and run:

```
docker build -t slim2alpine .
docker run slim2alpine
```

I found out that if I copy whole folder **/usr/local/bin** from **builder** to alpine then **python**, **pytest**, **celery** binaries become unavailable:

[image]

But if I copy to another slim (not alpine) everything works.

When I copy one by one binaries `COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/celery /usr/local/bin/pytest /usr/local/bin/` they work.

What do I miss? Is that possible copy whole **/usr/local/bin** folder?

Answer (score 2):

Alpine runs musl libc, I don't think wholesale copying binaries over from Debian (the slim base image) are going to be binary compatible. They will require a different libc, and probably won't link properly.